# How do I make a keyboard combo to input a set string into the currently selected text field?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I can't type accents and symbols on Ubuntu, so I'd like to be able to hit a specific set of keys to input a symbol or emoticon. Is there any way I could do this or something similar?

Comment: Does this help? https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en

Comment: Not quite, I’d also like to be able to input a string of multiple characters using one key combination (or using replacements). That does answer one part though! Thank you!